# Django generic login view creates variable automatically?

Tags: python, django, variables, authentication, django-generic-views

I am using the django generic login view. This is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
....
url(r'^login/$', login),
```

This is my login.html page:

```
<body>
<h1>User Login</h1>

{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password did not match. 
    Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
    {{ form.username }}</p>

    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
    {{ form.password }}</p>

    <input type="hidden" name="next" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
</body>
```

This is the generic login view:

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
      redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
      authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
      current_app=None, extra_context=None):
"""
Displays the login form and handles the login action.
"""
redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')
if request.method == "POST":
    form = authentication_form(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
        if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
            redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
        auth_login(request, form.get_user())

        if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            request.session.delete_test_cookie()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
else:
    form = authentication_form(request)

request.session.set_test_cookie()

current_site = get_current_site(request)

context = {
    'form': form,
    redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
    'site': current_site,
    'site_name': current_site.name,
}
if extra_context is not None:
    context.update(extra_context)
return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                        current_app=current_app)
```

Now, Once I successfully log in, it redirects me to the homepage since in my settings.py,

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'
```

This is my homepage view:

```
def main_page(request):
variables = {
 'head_title': 'Django Bookmarks',
'page_title': 'Welcome to Django Bookmarks',
'page_body': 'Where you can store and share bookmarks!',   
}
return render(request, 'main_page.html', variables)
```

and this is my homepage template (main_page.html):

```
<body>
{% if user.username %}
    <p>Welcome {{ user.username }}</p>
{% else %}
<p>Welcome unknown user, please <a href='/login'>Login</a> in order to get full access to the website.</p>
{% endif %}
<h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>
<p>{{ page_body }}</p>
</body>
```

Now, for some reason, the

```
{% if user.username %}
```

line executes to true after I sign the user in, even though in my homepage view, I didn't even create a 'user' variable / object. I'm wondering, where exactly is the variables 'user' created and how is it being sent as a variables to my main_page.html template?

Comment: BTW you have also `perms` in your template (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `user` variable is injected by a context processor of the auth module.

See [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/context_processors.py#L49)

Comment: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS includes that context processor by default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors

Comment: @synthomat hm, okay, so whenever I authenticate a user, the user variable is then sent to the url which I redirect to?

Comment: This variable is injected into the request object, which persists between all pages of the application.

Answer (score 1):

That is the [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.contrib.auth.middleware) assigning [`request.user`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2530735d2d57316d1df8177745e93a78de663ff7/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L14) (guaranteed to be one of `User` or `AnonymousUser`), then the `auth` context processor exposes `request.user` to the template and it's permissions as `user`, `perms`.